# How to clean the event from all attached methods

Tags: silverlight, events

I have a control, for example Button. I want to clean up event OnClick, but I don't know how much methods it calls and don't know names of methods (like: `btn.OnClickClear();`). I found this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb979826%28v=vs.95%29.aspx
but don't understand how to implement it in Silverlight.

---

I am using Silverlight 4. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if you mean this; but when you add an event listener on your Button like this:

```
btnName.Click += new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(OnClick);

void OnClick(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  // Handle event
}
```

You can remove it like this:

```
btnName.Click -= new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(OnClick);
```

From inside the Button class you can set the Click event to null like, which removes all event listeners I think.

```
this.Click = null;
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is not what I want. I said that I don't know names of the methods. I have one class, I have one event, I know that it calls one or more methods. How can I clean up this event? After clean up this event doesn't call any of methods.

Comment: You can set the name of the event to null from inside you class which removes all eventlisteners to that event, I updated the answer. Is that what you ment?

Comment: Yes, this is what I ment)) But, if I write this code: this.Click = null; I got an error: The event can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

Comment: You can only use that in the class where the event is sitting. Not from ouside the class or from a inherited class. So you cannot have a CustomButton which extends Button and in CustomButton clear the Click event of Button. Not sure if this is to prevent memory leaks but if so, once the button is disposed the eventlisteners will be removed automatic.

Comment: So how to disposed eventlisteners? only eventlisteners. Is it possible?

Comment: There is no need to dispose them, the GC will handle that for you without any issue. You wont have to clear them yourself to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: I need to clear event. This is not reason in memory leaks. So I just asked: how can I clean up some event??? Is it possible at all??

Comment: It should be possible but there is no easy solution for it, either should try use Reflection to do this, or make in your inheritence class a public NEW event, and reroute all all events. But this is far from pretty...

Comment: Thanx, this is what I want. Do you know how it to do using Reflection?